# Android URL images shuffle in listview

Tags: android, json, listview

I just noticed that when I loaded my images in a listview from a url, sometimes they cycle through stuff before it settles on the right one. How can I prevent that from happening?

This is my async task from my custom adapter

```
private class AsyncDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Bitmap>{

        private View view;
        private Bitmap bitmap = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if(bitmap!=null&&view!=null){
                ImageView newsIcon = (ImageView)view.getTag(R.id.newsIcon);
                newsIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
            view = (View)params[0];
            String uri = (String)params[1];
            try{
                InputStream inputStream = new URL(uri).openStream();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
```

This is my getview

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        if(position==0){

            NewsObj currNews = news.get(position);
            DataHandler dh;
            if(convertView==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstnews,parent,false);
                dh = new DataHandler();
                dh.newsTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
                dh.newsDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.newsDate);
                dh.newsIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.newsIcon);
                row.setTag(dh);
            }else{
                dh = (DataHandler)row.getTag();
            }
            NewsObj no = (NewsObj)this.getItem(position);
            row.setTag(R.id.newsIcon,row.findViewById(R.id.newsIcon));
            new AsyncDownloadTask().execute(row,no.getImgurl());
            dh.newsTitle.setText(no.getTitle());
            dh.newsDate.setText(no.getDate());

        }else{

            NewsObj currNews = news.get(position);
            DataHandler dh;
            if(convertView==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newslist,parent,false);
                dh = new DataHandler();
                dh.newsTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
                dh.newsDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.newsDate);
                dh.newsIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.newsIcon);
                row.setTag(dh);
            }else{
                dh = (DataHandler)row.getTag();
            }
            NewsObj no = (NewsObj)this.getItem(position);
            row.setTag(R.id.newsIcon, row.findViewById(R.id.newsIcon));
            new AsyncDownloadTask().execute(row,no.getImgurl());
            dh.newsTitle.setText(no.getTitle());
            dh.newsDate.setText(no.getDate());

        }
        return row;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a proper image loader like Picasso, Fresco, or Glide?

Comment: Unfortunately the requirements are to not use any external libraries

Comment: use picasso / glide for that its work for me

Comment: Yeah I can't use them unfortunately

Comment: Hmm, strange requirement. I see you are using the view holder pattern, which is good, however, there are 2 concerns 1) memory: you are loading an entire bitmap into a tiny ImageView 2) network: the  AsyncTask is going to be executed everytime a view is scrolled in and out of frame + the images won't be cleared from memory as new ones are loaded

Comment: Well the thing is that there would be a limited amount of items loaded per time so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it works but maybe you can put image uri string also in the DataHandler. And check for that in the postExecute so that only when it matches the last one it applies it:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(bitmap!=null&&view!=null && ((DataHandler)view.getTag()).uri.equals(this.uri){
            ImageView newsIcon = (ImageView)view.getTag(R.id.newsIcon);
            newsIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

And then also have a private String uri in the AsyncTask that gets set in `doInBackground`

Comment: sorry where do I get the uri from?

Comment: Right before you do `new AsyncDownloadTask().execute(row,no.getImgurl());` you could do `dh.uri = no.getImgurl()` for example

Comment: Sorry I understand the first part but I can't declare dh.uri because dh links a textview

Comment: Surely dh is just some class that you made yourself and you can extend it with any fields you like or not?

Answer (score 3):

one thing you are doing wrong which is causing this issue, you are binding your views to task. theoretically it will cause inconsistency of displaying image for example if your image view referenced into two  task, which ever task finish last will set bitmap. how you can solve this issue just set task reference as tag to your image view,before creating new task first get old task from your image view if its not null and not finished cancel it and create new task.

here is bit refactored code try this.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        DataHandler dh;
        if(position==0){

            NewsObj currNews = news.get(position);
            if(convertView==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstnews,parent,false);
                dh = new DataHandler();
                dh.newsTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
                dh.newsDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.newsDate);
                dh.newsIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.newsIcon);
                row.setTag(dh);
            }else{
                dh = (DataHandler)row.getTag();
            }
            NewsObj no = (NewsObj)this.getItem(position);
            row.setTag(R.id.newsIcon,row.findViewById(R.id.newsIcon));
            dh.newsTitle.setText(no.getTitle());
            dh.newsDate.setText(no.getDate());

        }else{

            NewsObj currNews = news.get(position);
            if(convertView==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newslist,parent,false);
                dh = new DataHandler();
                dh.newsTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
                dh.newsDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.newsDate);
                dh.newsIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.newsIcon);
                row.setTag(dh);
            }else{
                dh = (DataHandler)row.getTag();
            }
            NewsObj no = (NewsObj)this.getItem(position);
            row.setTag(R.id.newsIcon, row.findViewById(R.id.newsIcon));
            dh.newsTitle.setText(no.getTitle());
            dh.newsDate.setText(no.getDate());

        }
      AsyncTask task = (AsyncTask)dh.newsIcon.getTag();
      if(task!=null && task.getStatus()!=FINISHED){
      task.cancel();
      }
       task = new AsyncDownloadTask();
       dh.newsIcon.setTag(task);
       task.execute(row,no.getImgurl());

        return row;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry can you point out where in my code do I do this ? Is it this? row.setTag(R.id.newsIcon, row.findViewById(R.id.newsIcon));

Comment: new AsyncDownloadTask().execute(row,no.getImgurl());  in if and else clause. it will work fine for first visible items but as soon as you start scrolling every time new task will be created without canceling old task.

Comment: So should I remove it from the if else and declare it outside?

Comment: not sure do you need this line row.setTag(R.id.newsIcon,row.findViewById(R.id.newsIcon)); but you can do like this

Task task = (Task)row.getTag();
if(task!=null && task.isNofinished){
task.cancel();
}

task =new AsyncDownloadTask();
row.setTag(row);
task.execute(row,no.getImgurl());

Comment: Do I need an external library for task? I can't seem to get it

Comment: no no i just tried to write a sudo code for you. you can use the same AsyncTask.